# Create a simple shop's website with products list

Tags: plugin-recommendation

I need to create a webpage for the book store.

For now I need to create several static web pages and one page with list of products. I don't know how to create this list, I don't need any shopping carts and payments. Just plain products list with separate page for each product.

I also can consider commercial plugins.

Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 2):

Install the [Custom Post Type UI plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-post-type-ui/) and create a `Product` [custom post type](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types#Custom_Types). You can then create separate templates in your theme to display your products archive and posts.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to investigate the [**Simple Retail Menus**](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/simple-retail-menus/) plugin in the WordPress repository.  I haven't tried it yet, but it may be what you need.